# In Django multiple databases should not creat a test database by manage.py on 1 specific database

Tags: django, unit-testing, manage.py

In Django I'm using multple databases, but by testing the functionality 1 database of the multiple database should not create a test database if you run manage.py test **. How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your `settings.py` you can tell Django what database to use when testing.  Here is the code to do so if you would like to use `SQLite` for example:

#### settings.py:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'tests.db',
    }
```

`Django` creates a new database every time you run your `manage.py test`, so you would want to use **fixtures** in your `test.py` file to preload you database with data before running tests (if you need it preloaded with data).

To generate a fixture for the `User model` for example, use this code:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth.User --indent=2 > app_name/fixtures/admin.json
```

To use `fixtures` you would structure your `tests.py` like so:

#### tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    fixtures = [admin.json]

    def setUp(self):
        # other setup code here

    def test_the_obvious(self):
        assert True == True
```